# Offchain Storage lock vs compare-set/mutate function

Tags: database, offchain, offchain-storage

While using `offchain` workers when do we want to use a `StorageLock` and when would we want to use a `mutate` function on `StorageValueRef` since both of them are kind of lock on db.